# Using redux-thunks in Cypress

Tags: reactjs, redux, cypress, redux-thunk

I have a React app built using `Create React App` and `Redux` with `redux-thunk` which I want to test using `Cypress`. When dispatching thunks from Cypress (which I do when setting up tests) the dispatched actions in the thunk are not propagated to the intended store.

To highlight what I mean, here is some code. Consider a simple store

```js
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";

const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export { store };

if (window.Cypress) {
  window.testId = uuid();
  window.store = store;
}
```

and some thunk

```js
const myThunk = () => dispatch => {
  console.log(window.testId);
  dispatch({type: "RANDOM_ACTION"});
}
```

If dispatch this action inside Cypress via

```js
cy.window().its("store").invoke("dispatch", myThunk());
```

the logged `testId` will not be the same as if running `console.log(window.testId)` in the dev console in the browser.

Do anyone know have an idea how to approach this situation?
Thankful for advice

Comment: What kind of tests are you trying to write in Cypress? End-to-end tests shouldn't have to know anything about the underlying implementation, certainly not details like action objects.

Comment: It's for setting up tests, such as creating a few users and populating it with posts. For example, login in before a test. We do this in a thunk which performs an api call and then updates the Redux state to signal the user is logged in

Comment: Although I realized, the few thunks that are really needed (such as login) can be exposed directly on window object

Comment: You can use either APIs or UI to accomplish this. We have some custom commands for preparing some UI state before a test as well as some that are written with APIs.

Comment: *testId will not be the same* - `uuid()` is random, so to be clear, is the dev console you refer to the one in the Cypress test browser?

Comment: Correct @RichardMatsen, the dev console is in the Cypress console, so they should be the same.

Comment: Ok... so Cypress is reloading the app (and re-running `uuid()`). For the purpose of the test, does testId have to be random, can it be a static uuid? At least, it seems that the thunk invocation from the test is working.

Comment: ...or set `window.testId = uuid()` from within the test. Not clear to me what the problem is, but this blog [Detect page reload from Cypress test](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/detect-page-reload/) has some ideas.

Comment: The `testId` was to demonstrate that the thunk is not executed with the correct `window` context (maybe not unexpected because of scoping), it's not something I'll use.  

The root of the problem is that when invoking dispatch on a thunk this way, the changes did not seem to apply to the store.